# Navigational Formatting CSS3

Tags: html, layout, css, navigation

I am trying to reproduce the following navigation menu but I am having a few issues interms of the layout and spacing of the buttons.

Also with the Composer button would I just set the icon as a background image?

**Original:**

[image]

**My Attempt:**

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<div class="options">
                <nav class="mainOptions">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a class="composer" href="#">Composer</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Address Books</a></li>
                        <li class="active"><a href="#" target="_self" title="View Messages Scheduled for Future Delivery">Scheduled Messages</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" target="_self" title="Message Templates for you or your organisation">Templates</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </nav>
```

**CSS:**

```
.options{
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
}
.mainOptions{
    float:left;
    margin:0 15px 0 20px;
    color:#fff;
    width:700px;
    height:50px;
}
.mainOptions a.composer{
    width:50px;
    height:40px;
    color:#fff;
    background: #184c82; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #184c82 0%, #022243 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#184c82), color-stop(100%,#022243)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #184c82 0%,#022243 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #184c82 0%,#022243 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #184c82 0%,#022243 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top,  #184c82 0%,#022243 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#184c82', endColorstr='#022243',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
.mainOptions .composerIcon{
    display:inline-block;
    width:14px;
    height:14px;
    background:url('../images/composer.png') no-repeat -96px -72px;
}
.mainOptions ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:4px 10px 4px;
    border-radius:4px;
}
.mainOptions li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:13px;
    line-height:18px;
    color:#184C82;
}
.mainOptions li{
    width:140px;
    text-align:center;
}
.mainOptions li.active{
    background-color:#7E98B3;
    color:#FFF;
}
```

Comment: If the original is from a web-page, you can easily view the CSS styles that define it.

Comment: Why is there no `.composerIcon` in your HTML code?

Comment: FYI [don't use `width: 100%` when you really need `width: auto`](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201112/the_difference_between_widthauto_and_width100/) (and you don't need either on a div, it's already `auto`)

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Its from a graphic I have been given

Comment: @FelipeAlsacreations I have not got that far yet but could I not use background-image in .composer?  I cannot seem to get the widths and heights correct for the menu items

Comment: Don't use `height` property (except on some elements when they contain decoration images for examples). What you want is `min-height` and if for any reason (text zoom, larger fonts on some OS/browsers like Firefox/Ubuntu and Safari/OS X, etc) your menu is rendered on 2 lines or more than expected, then it'll still be readable. And it doesn't change anything in the general case, you'll still have (at least) the height you needed.

Comment: Icon > yes it can (should) be a background-image as it's decorative (the link text already says that you can write something if you click). But as there's also linear-gradient(s) (and they are values of the property background-image), then you've a multiple background on this `a` and it's more complicated to write.

Comment: @FelipeAlsacreations Could you provide an answer with maybe a jsfiddle so I can see what you mean.  I am a visual learner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did based off of what you had. It almost looks like the Composer button has a different font but I'm not positive. Just add the image into the Composer button and then it's pretty close.

http://jsfiddle.net/hhKah/1/

Comment: David,  I have tried adding it into the Composer css as a background image using background-image:url('../images/composer.png') no-repeat; but I cannot see it.  The image in question is http://jzm.co.nz/clients/dev/_assets/images/composer.png

Comment: David, I also note on my index.html in /dev/ my .pageHelp is not showing correctly but when I load that section of code up to jsfiddle.net it shows fine.  Any ideas?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hhKah/2/ - 

The reason the Composer icon did not work for you is because you set it as a background image over the existing Composer background. I modified the link I sent you to include the Composer icon. In CSS3 you can have more than one background, but for this example I just added an <img> tag. For your second question, I'm not sure what .pageHelp is, you're going to have to be more specific.

Comment: Thank you David,  I will write another question regarding the Page Help

Comment: You can find it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10822982/css3-icon-layout-formatting